# "yum update" error. How to handle this?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, yum, perl

I have an ec2 instance and I'm trying to update all packages.

But the problem is when I execute "yum update" it shows the message:

```
Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/Cwd.pm conflicts between attempted installs of perl-Cwd-2.21-1.2.el6.rf.x86_64 and perl-PathTools-3.40-3.4.amzn1.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/auto/Cwd/Cwd.so conflicts between attempted installs of perl-Cwd-2.21-1.2.el6.rf.x86_64 and perl-PathTools-3.40-3.4.amzn1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man3/Cwd.3pm.gz conflicts between attempted installs of perl-Cwd-2.21-1.2.el6.rf.x86_64 and perl-PathTools-3.40-3.4.amzn1.x86_64
```

My Linux version is: 3.4.48-45.46.amzn1.x86_64 Red Hat 4.6.3-2

I tried to exclude "perl" from the updates, but the problem is that nginx need this perl update.

Any help how to handle this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have an incompatible repository "rpmforge". This only works on RHEL and clones, and isn't compatible with Amazon Linux (which used to be a RHEL clone, but isn't anymore).

You have a couple of options:

1. Remove the rpmforge repository and try again. Note that you might not be able to do this if you actually need packages from this repository.
2. The preferred option: Stop using Amazon Linux. Our pages are full of questions from people whose problems were directly traceable to quality control problems in Amazon's packages.

Comment: I disabled the rpmforge repository and it worked, thanks! :) To change from Amazon Linux, do I have to create another instance and reconfigure step by step with my app? Or is there any easier way?

Comment: Yes, you would have to create a new instance and redeploy your app.

Comment: For those who do not know how to disable rpmforge repository, I did it by editing `/etc/yum.repos.d/rpmforge.repo` and change the `enabled` flag to 0.